# How to change the text of a button inside a drop down list

Tags: c#, html, asp.net

```
<div id="ddlPreferences" runat="server" class="dropdown pull-left div-margin" visible="true">
<button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="btnUser" data-toggle="dropdown">***Account***
span class="caret"></span>
                        </button>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="menu1">
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuItem" tabindex="-1" href="/Account/Profile.aspx">Profile</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuItem" tabindex="-1" href="/Account/Logout.aspx">Logout</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuItem" tabindex="-1" href="/Account/ChangePassword.aspx">Change Password</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuItem" tabindex="-1" href="/Account/Upload.aspx">Upload Post</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation"><a role="menuItem" tabindex="-1" href="/Account/Administration.aspx">Account Management</a></li>
                            <li role="presentation" class="divider"></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

I am trying to dynamically change the word account on the second line to the current users user name I have tried a couple of things but cannot seem to make it work. Any advice would be welcomed.

Comment: why all the negative karma guys? it was my first post at least leave a reason why it got down voted so I can make it better for next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a label and you can then change it behind code.

```
asp:label id="lblUpload" runat="server" text="upload">
```

Code behind :
lblUpload.text ="dynamic value"

You can also use a html input label.

Comment: where does the label go? I'm fairly new to html and master sites.

Comment: edit** after trying it a couple of time I got it to work thanks again man!

Answer (score 0):

Replace html button with

```
<asp:button id="id" runat="server" text="urText" />
```

Then whenever u want to change text, change it via code as:

```
id.Text="Your desired text";
```